# FBSDK doesn’t return readPermissions on signing in with Native App

Tags: ios, facebook, firebase, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I use Facebook SDK 4.13.1 in my Swift 2.3 project. When I try to Login with Facebook through simulator, on authorizing user with Facebook, it returns with user information successfully. But when I try to do the same on my iOS Device that lets me switch to the native Facebook App and then returns to my application, none of the user’s information is returned. This also happens when I try to login with Facebook via Safari on my iOS Device.

This process worked perfectly in simulator, as well as on iOS Device before, and I’ve not updated any SDKs that might be dependent.

Here’s how I retrieve user’s information:

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    if let error = error {
        print("Facebook Login Button Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    else {

        guard let accessToken:FBSDKAccessToken? = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() else {

            self.statusLabel.alpha = 0
            self.statusLabel.text = "Oops! There was a problem requesting access from Facebook."
            self.statusLabel.fadeIn(completion: {
                (finished: Bool) -> Void in
                self.statusLabel.fadeOut()
            })

            return
        }

        if accessToken?.tokenString != nil {

            let credential = FIRFacebookAuthProvider.credentialWithAccessToken(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString)



            FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCredential(credential) { (user, error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)

                    return
                }
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SignUpViewControllerSegue", sender: nil)
            }
        }
        else {


            print("Access Token not granted")
            }
        }
    }

func loginButtonWillLogin(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) -> Bool {
    loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends", "user_location"];

    return true

}
```

Comment: did you test with same user which used in simulator ?

Comment: @KKRocks yes it’s the same user.